# How to get service fee when deploying smart contract (Web3.js)

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am trying to get service fee from every contract deployment on my website frontend, when I run this, the contract is being deployed to testnet successfully but the amount I specified in 6th argument (fee) is not sent to the wallet address in the 5th argument.

```js
import Web3 from 'web3';

const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
const token = { abi: [], bytecode: '' } // assume I have ABI & bytecode string

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(token.abi);

const fee = 1000000; // the fee amount I want to receive from every deployment

const deployer = contract.deploy({ 
  data: '0x' + token.bytecode,
  arguments: [
    "Test token", // token name
    "TST", // token symbol
    18, // decimals
    1000000000000000000000, // supply
    '0x920b819b1b27fb969c4344d66759dfC9d58b6f1e', // my metamask address that I want to receive fee to
    fee,
  ],
});

const gas = await deployer.estimateGas({ from: accounts[0], value: fee });

deployer.send({
  from: accounts[0],
  gas: gas,
  value: fee,
});
```

Here is the main part of my solidity file

```
pragma solidity =0.8.19;

contract StandardToken is IERC20, Ownable, BaseToken {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    uint256 public constant VERSION = 1;

    mapping(address => uint256) private _balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) private _allowances;

    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;
    uint8 private _decimals;
    uint256 private _totalSupply;

    constructor(
        string memory name_,
        string memory symbol_,
        uint8 decimals_,
        uint256 totalSupply_,
        address serviceFeeReceiver_,
        uint256 serviceFee_
    ) payable {
        _name = name_;
        _symbol = symbol_;
        _decimals = decimals_;
        _mint(owner(), totalSupply_);

        emit TokenCreated(owner(), address(this), TokenType.standard, VERSION);
        
        payable(serviceFeeReceiver_).transfer(serviceFee_);
    }
   
    // ...
```

Comment: Was the contract deployed? If the contract failed for some reason it will revert undoing any change. If the contract deployed correctly then the fee should be in the receiver wallet.